# Pushing Application Logs to AWS CloudWatch on demand

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I am working on pushing application logs(Tomcat) to cloudwatch on demand.I found a method to send logs to cloudwatch after writing them to log files.
Could someone please help me to figure out, can we send logs on demand to cloudwatch without saving them in a log file.

Comment: What logging framework are you using? There are several libraries that let you write directly to CloudWatch, including [one that I wrote for Log4J 1.x](https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders). Google shows several others for Logback and Log4J 2.x, and I'm sure you'd find one for JavaUtilLogging if you searched.

Comment: I am using Log4j framework.Thanks for the information

Comment: @kdgregory
I configured aws-appender in my application and I'm getting "log4j:WARN appender not properly configured: writer is null
" investigate a lot on this, but unable to find an answer.Please help me to figure out this.

Comment: Below are the configurations
**log4j.xml**
`<appender name="cloudwatch" class="com.kdgregory.log4j.aws.CloudWatchAppender">
        <param name="logGroup" value="logGroupName"/>
        <param name="logStream" value="logStreamName"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="info" /> 
         <appender-ref ref="cloudwatch"/> 
    </root>`

Comment: The most likely cause is that you don't have the correct permissions, as described [in the docs](https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders/blob/master/docs/cloudwatch.md#permissions). There should be more "log4j" messages that give details about the reason. You can also use `-Dlog4j.configDebug=true` on the command line to dump debug-level information about Log4J startup.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tried the configuration from your comment and had no problems. I then deleted my AWS credentials and saw the following on the console: `log4j:ERROR initialization failed: unable to configure log group/stream`, followed by an exception. Are you seeing the same thing?

Comment: Also, you're using Log4J version **1**, correct?

Comment: @kdgregory Thank you for the quick response, yes i am using log4j 1.2.17 and jdk 1.7.
I am not getting "log4j:ERROR initialization failed: unable to configure log group/stream", also I added aws-appenders 1.2.1 and aws-java-sdk 1.11.299 dependencies as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but without knowing your exact build configuration there's not much that I can do to help. The "writer is null" message indicates that there's something wrong with the configuration, such that the appender can't be initialized or experiences an error while trying to write. However, to the best of my knowledge every code path that could lead to this will log a message explaining _why_ the appender can't write.

Comment: My best suggestion is that you try building the example program, replacing the `log4j.properties` file with your won configuration (note that you'll also have to make an explicit call to `DOMConfigurator` in `main()` to make this work).